# html5-canvas on iphone6 does not scale properly

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas which plays a video inside, using [phoboslab/jsmpeg](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg);

the canvas css-width fills its parent:
    css-width = 100%
and the width-attribute is set to the video-dimension:
    width-attribute = 1280

BUT
on iphone6, it reports that everything is set as I want to, but the video is too big
--> I only see the top-left detail of the video.

any solution is well appreciated!
thanks.

**EDIT**

it seems that the cause of the problems is a *missing* re-rendering of the via javascript changed DOM through the browser 
--> every code/object/property is changed as it was supposed to happen, but the browser (in this case : safari) doesn't show the changes in its displayed rendering of the page

anyway, that's no fix , just a assumption and I am still researching the solution . . .

Comment: Does this only happen on an iPhone 6 and have you tested it on other devices? In the jsmpeg docs it says under Limitations that 'the width of the MPEG video has to be a multiple of 2'. The width of a regular iPhone 6 is 375px (an odd number). I wonder if this is the issue?

Comment: Hi Jared, actually we have seen it on other iPhones as well, but only in safari and only so persistent on the 6. Android works fine (so far...)

I thought with 'the width of the MPEG' is meant only the actual width of the file, not the html-element; but that could be the missing pointer in the direction of a solution ...! (checking it out . . .)

Comment: Video-width is a multiple of 2 - therefore not the problem...

Comment: It could be an issue with retina.  Try to make your canvas high res. [Paul Lewis](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/) has more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css-width/-height of the canvas have to get set to something else than they would be with 100%. (e.g. 101%)
Only this (after trying 9 other methods of a redraw/repaint) induces Safari to render it correctly.